# How do I draw an array with markers (arrows) showing pointers, and braces telling something about part of the range?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I need my output to be like:

[image: array pic]

However, I'm new to LaTeX and even newer to Tikz. I can draw basic shapes like rectangles and circles, but this is beyond my knowledge as of yet. I would like to learn how to make the following.

I can't figure out how to add the pointers(i and j with the arrows) or the braces (abc and def).

Is there a ready made package that can do this? If not, how do I go about doing this in Tikz?

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution can be done with Tikz. This is the result

[image]

and this is the code.

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        box/.style={rectangle,draw=black, ultra thick, minimum size=1cm},
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\foreach \x/\y in {0/9, 1/5,2/13,3/19,4/12,5/8,6/7,7/4,8/21,9/2,10/6,11/11}
        \node[box] at (\x,0){\y};

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror},thick] (-.5,-.7) -- node[below]{abc} (3.5,-.7);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror},thick] (3.5,-.7) -- node[below]{def} (7.5,-.7);
\draw[->,very thick] (3,1.2) --  node[above,yshift=2mm]{i} (3,.7);
\draw[->,very thick] (7,1.2) --  node[above,yshift=2mm]{j} (7,.7);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Note:** the loop can be implemented in an elegant and efficient way as has suggested in the comment below by @Andrew

`@\foreach \y [count=\x] in {9,5,13,19,12,8,7,4,21,2,6,11}{\node[box] at (\x-1,0){\y};}`

Comment: You simplify the loop as `\foreach \y [count=\x] in {9,5,13,19,12,8,7,4,21,2,6,11}{\node[box] at (\x-1,0){\y};}`.

Comment: @Andrew, good point.